# MsSQL Server 2008 R2 Setup Discovery Report shows instance but Management studio sees nothing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've just installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (64 bits with BI) on a windows dedicated server with the cheap Web Edition.

I launched
 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup Discovery Report which says:
Product Instance    Instance ID 
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2    SQLEXPRESS2008

But when I run sql server management studio, it shows (local), when I try to connect with sa and password it fails saying

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to (local).
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I have checked that SQL Server is running within SQL Server Management Configuration. Sql server agent is not running, do I need it ?

Comment: Is this the right forum to ask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't SQL Server Express install as a named instance by default?  Try "(local)\SQLEXPRESS".  Also make sure that the SQL Server Browser service is running.  You need it to connect to a named instance.

Comment: Thank you very very very very very very much !!! I don't know why sql browser isn't started after install, this never occured to me before :)

Comment: Isn't this a bug of sql server install ? I did the install twice and it did reproduce.